# Fetch http://localhost:3001/ from Chrome Extension with React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, cors, azure-cosmosdb

I have seen some similar problems and solutions where people want to hit `http://localhost:3001/some_url` and use `cors` to do so.

But my problem is a little different. My web app is not a website but a web-extension.

SO far I cannot find a way to fetch from http://localhost:3001/url even with using cors.

What I have tried is:

Server:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3001/url" // restrict calls to those this address
    
  })
);
```

In `background.js` file:

```
create(urls){
    console.log(urls);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'+'http://localhost:3001/url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(urls),
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
        }
      })
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(json => resolve(json))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

I have also added `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/url"` in `packages.json`.

I am still getting the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/url' from origin 'chrome-extension://extension_id' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3001/url' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Is there any way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding a path `/url` to the origin, but an [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin) is:

> Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), host
> (domain), and port of the URL used to access it

Try using `http://localhost:3001` as the origin value.

Comment: Ok. I just tried that. If I don't add the `cors-anywhere-heroku`... I get the same error only except the `/url `. If I add the `cors-anywhere-heroku`.... along with `http://localhost:3001` I am getting `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:3001:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded `